# django.import-export ImportExportMixin customisation

Tags: django, admin, django-import-export

I am using  ImportExportMixin  to add the import export buttons to my admin page: [image]

i write it like this :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin

class PlayerAdmin(ImportExportMixin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in Player._meta.fields]

admin.site.register(Player,PlayerAdmin)
```

When I do th export I get something like this :

`[{"id": 1, "name": "player1", "date_birth": "1997-01-01", "tshirtnumber": 19, "club": 1, "poste": "ST"}]`

The club is a ForeingKey and I want the name of the club not the id. so what to do ?
and please I need the same thing for the import I mean I want to import players with their club name .

I am expecting :

`[{"id": 1, "name": "player1", "date_birth": "1997-01-01", "tshirtnumber": 19, "club": "chelsea", "poste": "ST"}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#model-relations) you can define the relation in the `fields` list of your resource:

```py
class PlayerResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        # add all your export fields
        fields = ("id", "name", "club__name")
```

For [importing relations](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#foreign-key-relations), declare a `ForeignKeyWidget`:

```py
class PlayerResource(ModelResource):
     # values here might be different depending on your model
     club = fields.Field(
        column_name='club',
        attribute='club',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Club, field='name'))


    class Meta:
        model = Player
        # ...
```